# Commenting Highlighted code in Netbeans

Tags: css, netbeans, syntax, comments

Using the latest version of Netbeans and trying to use the toggle comment button to comment out **only** the highlighted text, but netbeans ends up commenting out the entire line of CSS code.

Is there any way to work around this? Because I have to type out /* */ manually in order to comment without affecting the entire line.

Answer (score 3):

there are two short cuts to comment out sections of text

```
ctrl + shift + c     comment out selected lines
ctrl + /             toggle on off comments section
```

The way to work around it is by creating a new line before and after the section of text you want to comment out.